# In SimpleStrategy, can coordinator node also store the replica?

Tags: cassandra

The Client makes a data read request to Node #1 (the coordinator). The grey heptagon indicates the hash value of the key the client requested. Which node will serve the data to the client? Where will the replica of the data be stored?
Replication Factor of 2 and i use simple strategy
in the picture it should be #1,#2 to store the replicas, but #1 is a coordinator, will this affect anything?
will it change to #2,#3 to store the replicas beacuase of #1 is the coordinaotr?
A #1,#2
B #2  #3
A or B has the replicas?

[image: The Ring]

Comment: can you please expand the question? What you want to clarify?

Comment: just upload my question, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinator node stores data based on hintedhandoff value on cassandra.yaml if any replica node goes down.

Comment: Just update my question, Could you tell me the answer in this question?

Comment: Cap.W, above answer was your previous question.

Comment: For this, any node can become coordinator node based on token ranges and data will be replicated on Cassandra ring clock wise if your have 2 replication factor then 2 copy of data will be stored.

Comment: but which two node will stored those replica?  #1#2 or #2#3?

Comment: It depends upon hash value if primary ranges ranges lies between 1-2 then other replica clockwise will be placed on Cassandra ring it may 2-3 or 3-4.

Comment: what if the hash value is between #5 and #1 as shown in the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Coordinator node does all the communication with the client. It works as a proxy and forwards read/write request to other nodes (where a replica exists/should go) and then returns the result to the client.

As far as where the replica goes is concerned, it depends on what's the hash value of the key is. Each vNode has a range assigned to it. So, if hash of the key the data you are looking for is 123, and a vNode on machine #5 is responsible for storing the key range from 99 - 420, it will go there.

Comment: can the coordinator also be the place where the replica exists? (Just update the question again)

Comment: Yes. Any node can be a coordinator node.

Comment: Can a coordinator node also store the replica? If a node has already become a coordinator, and according to the simplestrategy, it should store the replica too, should we skip this coordinator node?

Comment: 1. Yes, that's possible but not necessary. 2. No, that's wrong. SimpleStrategy just says, "data is placed on the node determined by partitioner. If there are more than zero replicas, they are stored on successive nodes without any consideration of topology." It does not say anything about coordinator. If coincidently the coordinator happen to be the node that, according to the partitioner, is also the node where data should be stored, the data will be stored on the coordinator node.